# Why does my image switcher not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mouseover

Visit : to see my example: http://www.nycthirst.com/test-space/test-orig-best.html

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--


div#GHOLD { position: relative; width: 400px; height: 464px; 
          }
div.gname { position: absolute; top: 7px; left: 0px; height: 23px;  text-align: center;
            /*border: solid black 1px; padding-top: 4px;*/
            z-index: 20;
          }
div.bname { position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 0px; height: 27px;  text-align: center;
            padding-top: 4px;
            /*border:solid black 1px;*/
            z-index: 25;
          }
div.ihold { position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 0px; 
            width: 400px; height: 360px; z-index: 10; 
          }
img.bgraph { border: none; width: 400px; height: 360px; z-index: 10; }

-->
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function graphShow(which)

{
var ghold = document.getElementById("GHOLD");
var gdivs = ghold.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
gdivs[0].className = gdivs[1].className = gdivs[2].className = "gname";
gdivs[which].className = "bname";
gdivs[3].style.zIndex = gdivs[4].style.zIndex = gdivs[5].style.zIndex = 10;
gdivs[which+3].style.zIndex = 15;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="GHOLD">
  <div class="bname" style="left: 39px;  width: 77px; height: 135px; top: 35px;" onMouseOver="graphShow(1);"></div>
  <div class="gname" style="left: 162px; width: 77px; height: 135px; top: 35px;" onMouseOver="graphShow(0);"></div>
  <div class="gname" style="left: 280px; width: 77px; height: 135px; top: 35px;" onMouseOver="graphShow(2);"></div>
  <div class="ihold" style="z-index: 15;">
    <img class="bgraph" src="http://www.asme.org/wwwasmeorg/media/ASMEMedia/Events/Energy/energy_landing_page_drop1.png" alt="95 percent">
  </div>
  <div class="ihold">
    <img class="bgraph" src="http://www.asme.org/wwwasmeorg/media/ASMEMedia/Events/Energy/energy_landing_page_drop2.png" alt="69 percent" style="z-index: 10;">
  </div>
  <div class="ihold">
    <img class="bgraph" src="http://www.asme.org/wwwasmeorg/media/ASMEMedia/Events/Energy/energy_landing_page_drop3.png" alt="52 percent" style="z-index: 10;">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html
```

>

So here is the deal the page code above works perfectly in firefox and chrome. It does not do a thing in IE. The idea is on a mouse over or over state the background image will change. IF there is an easier solution I would love to see it. I am a bit of a novice with Javascript.

Comment: Browsers have supported `:hover` on arbitrary elements for years now.  Just saying.  You don't really need JS for this.

Comment: I understand the Browsers support :hover however if you looked at the example I would have to get 3 images to change on a single hover state.

Comment: That's mostly cause of how the images are sliced.  If you sliced them so that each one was either one large image or one small image...and made each large image a child of the corresponding small one's div...hold on, lemme whip up an example.

Comment: When one image becomes large the other 2 images have to become small. I can achieve it with each single image just not the other 2.

Comment: Consider that when you're mousing over one of the drops, *you're not mousing over the other two*.  So with CSS, they'll become smaller automatically due to their not being hovered over.

Comment: Very very half-assed example: http://jsfiddle.net/QTAja/ .  Picture the pink boxes as your existing graphic with all the images small, and the mouseover images with the small drops sliced out of them.

Comment: It does not seem to run.

Comment: Oops.  http://jsfiddle.net/QTAja/2/  (includes settings for background and image height) works in Chrome and IE9, and would work in IE7/8 except that JSFiddle seems to really screw up in them.

Comment: That does not do what this example does http://www.nycthirst.com/test-space/test-orig-best.html nor could it. Remember it starts in big drop phase if the drop on the left gets big the drop in the middle gets small.

Comment: Chao your solution seemed to be change the problem.

Comment: Sorry...what you apparently want looked like mouseover bugs (not changing the image back on mouseout, starting with one already selected, etc).  Usually when one wants a change to be persistent, it's in response to some affirmative action, usually a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't seem to like passing mouse events to elements that look invisible to it.  If you don't have a background or visible text on your trigger divs, the mouseover event just passes right through them.

You basically have to give the trigger divs a background, or content, that covers the area you want mouseovers to happen on.  IE doesn't care about the content of the background, as long as it's there and isn't the color "transparent". You should even be able to get away with using a 1x1 transparent GIF as the background, as long as you tile it.